# Which Arduino Board should I start with?

Tags: arduino-uno

I am interested in Arduino projects. I want to learn to develop my own Arduino based system. The problem is I am not sure which Adruino board must I start with. Any ideas are appreciated, I have searched many discussion forum but could not find a satisfactory answer.

My questions are:

1. Which Arduino Board should I start with?
2. Is it possible to work on Arduino based projects without the board; like having a simulation of the board? If so how?

Comment: Start, exactly as your question tag says, with an Uno.

Comment: And I don't know of any Arduino simulators that don't cost less than the price of 50 Unos.

Comment: @chaaarlie2 Okay that is fine, any recommendations or points I must consider to get started well?

Comment: As @rslite says, get a starter kit. But before you get anything, **buy a book**. It will be more educational in the first chapter alone than any answer here will be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My advice:
 - get a model with USB port (some do not have one)
 - the DUE might seem attractive, but you have less libraries available and less examples, I'd recommend it more as follow up
 - you will get frustrated if you do not know how to code, at least a bit, so if you have not programmed before, you might want to spend some time trying simple stuff just with your PC
 - same about electronics: if you do not have previous experience, it might be preferable to play a bit with a breadboard and some components (LEDs, resistors, switches, etc.); this will reduce the likelyhood that you fry your Arduino. Remember to buy some cables MM/MF/FF, you will end up needing all of them, sooner or later. For powering the board, you can find nice power supplies that cn be powered by a USB cable.

I have bought UNOR3 clones at $4-$5 on ebay, so if you can afford it, I'd suggest you buy a couple, that will enable you playing with I2C master slave and similar configurations.

Comment: Well, thanks for the idea. I have a good programming back ground: C, VB, Java, PHP,HTML and JavaScript. As of now I am specializing with Java, C and C++, however, I lack an electronics background. I visited Ebay and found too many boards that have the same tug as one I am looking for. If please you can point for me one that I can start with from [this list](http://www.ebay.com/bhp/arduino-uno-r3)

Comment: this is what I would recommend:
http://www.ebay.com/itm/Hot-Sale-ATmega328P-CH340G-UNO-R3-Board-Free-USB-Cable-for-Arduino-DIY-DJNG-/351337582344?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item51cd5a0f08

Comment: this is a bread board (but there are many other types):
http://www.ebay.com/itm/Prototyping-Prototype-Shield-ProtoShield-Mini-Breadboard-for-Arduino-UNO-R3-Mega-/360919191173?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_77&hash=item540875ce85

Comment: this is a variant I have never used:
http://www.ebay.com/itm/UNO-R3-ATmega328P-CH340-Mini-USB-Board-for-Compatible-Arduino-NEW-/281685195762?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item4195befbf2

Comment: this is an example of cables, i advice buying male/male male/female female/female:
http://www.ebay.com/itm/40PCS-Dupont-Wire-Color-Jumper-Cable-2-54mm-1P-1P-Male-to-Female-20cm-WC-/221480820368?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item3391491e90

Comment: some rgb led:
http://www.ebay.com/itm/50pcs-Ultra-Bright-5mm-4-pin-RGB-Diffused-Common-Anode-LED-light-Red-Green-Blue-/281487760818?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item4189fa5db2

And don't forget the resistors (see the LED page).

Comment: Thanks very much for the ideas, I will settle for what you have recommended.

Comment: If you find the answer useful, please remember to upvote it :-)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your budget you could start with an Arduino Uno starter kit that will include the Arduino, breadboard and wires plus different sensors (like [this one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00K6PYGQ8) - but there are others with less peripherals and cheaper).

If you have a lower budget you can still buy the arduino and many separate sensors/LEDs etc from eBay.

By googling you'll find a lot of tutorials about getting started with the hardware that you bought.